# нужно, чтобы при выборе первой радиокнопки, после нажатия на кнопку кек, исчезал 1 элемент и появлялся другой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

хотел сделать так чтобы при выборе первой радиокнопки и нажатии на кнопку kek, полностью исчезал элемент test1 и открывался элемент test2, но ничего не происходит

```js
for (var value = 1) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lol").click(function() {
      $("#test1").hide();
      $("#test2").show();
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#test2 {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test1">
  <p><b>********</b></p>
  <label>
        <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="1"> Не дзен</p>
      </label>
  <label>
        <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="2"> Дзен</p>
      </label>
  <label>
        <p><input name="dzen" type="radio" value="3"> Полный дзен</p>
      </label>
</div>
<div id="test2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<button id="lol">kek</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно поправить скрипт следующим образом:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#lol").click(function(){
        if($("input[name=dzen]:checked").val() == 1) {
            $("#test1").hide();
            $("#test2").show();
        }
    });
});
```